# How to process 0000-00-00 date in jdbc MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, jdbc

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
```

Originating from this code:

```
Date internalDate = rs.getDate(idx++);
```

Where `rs` is a `ResultSet`.

So this is fine to me - I know there are zero'ed dates in the database and I need to be able to read these and convert them into an appropriate (probably null) data in my downstream data structures.  The problem is I don't know how to retrieve it and get a "soft" error.  I thought about wrapping this line in a try/catch for SQLException but understand this will break validity of the ResultSet.

Is it possible to read this value in another way without throwing a SQLException?

Comment: I can't remember of the top of my head, but can't you use `rs.getString()` first, check if for '0000-00-00' and then do `getDate()`?

Comment: Why don't you update the values directly in the database. After all `0000-00-00` isn't a valid date and should not have been stored in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - basically yes, I would like to do that but it's a huge table that we aren't able to modify easily.  So I'll go with one of the patches suggested by you or Bohemian.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)'s answer, however if you don't have control over the connection, you could change the query to return a `null` instead:

```
select
    ...
    case when my_date_col = '0000-00-00' then null else my_date_col end as my_date_col,
    ...
```

or the slightly more terse, but mysql-only, option:

```
    if(my_date_col = '0000-00-00', null, my_date_col) as my_date_col
```

Also, caution is advised changing the entire application's JDBC behaviour as you may break code that relies on such dates being returned - perhaps they use `rs.getString(i)` instead. You would have to regression test all other queries to be sure.

Comment: Nice idea. I'd probably update all those invalid DATE values to NULL in the database.

Answer (score 10):

You need to tell the JDBC driver to convert them to NULL. This is done by passing a connection property name `zeroDateTimeBehavior` with the value `convertToNull`

For more details see the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading.html

Comment: +! No sour grapes, but a warning here: Caution is advised changing the entire application's JDBC behaviour as you may break code that relies on such dates being returned - perhaps they use `rs.getString(i)` instead. You would have to regression test all other queries to be sure.

Comment: @Bohemian: how can the application rely on those dates being returned if the JDBC driver throws an exception?

Comment: Who said anything about dates? Other row set processing may only use `getString()` on the column. The Exception is only thrown when `getDate()` is called, so if it's never called who knows what effect changing the driver will have. Just for the record, I would do your approach first if possible and fix anything that broke (probably nothing).

Comment: @Bohemian: if the application is using `getString()` on a `DATE` column it's broken anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `rs.getString()` and parsing the `String` yourself. If it is all 0s, then use a null `Date` reference. If not, create an appropriate `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

Set the column Allow Null, and Set Default Value at Column : 1900-01-01 was my best solution...

[image: Date Setting]

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert this String result to a date by using "simpleDateFormat.parse(yourValue)"
2. Get day or year or month value from that date ( whichever you want)
3. This will return int value
4. Check if it is 0
5. If it is zero set date equal to null.