# Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, java.util.date

I'm working on some project which needs to extract data from DB and I use Spring MVC to build model from DB for selecting data.

Here is the problem with my **JSP page:**

```
<form action="result" method="get" >
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Date to select:</th>
<th>Name to select:</th>
<th>Type to select:</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><form:select  path="listOfDates">
<form:option value="NONE"> --SELECT--</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfDates}"></form:options>
</form:select>
</td>  
<td><form:select  path="listOfInstitutionsNames">
<form:option value="NONE"> --SELECT--</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfInstitutionsNames}"></form:options>
</form:select>
</td>
<td>
<form:select  path="listOfInstitutionsTypes">
<form:option value="NONE"> --SELECT--</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfInstitutionsTypes}"></form:options>
</form:select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Извлечь"/></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>

</table>
</form>
```

As you can see I try to use `<form:select>` from `Spring` tag library.
**Question:**
but when it's preparing my model with this **controller:**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{ 

    @Autowired
    private ControllerSupportClass controllerSupportClass; 


        @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String search(Model model) {
            List<Date> listOfDates = controllerSupportClass.findAllDatesForm();
            List<String> listOfInstitutionsNames = controllerSupportClass.findAllInstitutionsForm();
            List<String> listOfInstitutionsTypes = controllerSupportClass.findAllTypesForm();
            model.addAttribute("listOfInstitutionsTypes", listOfInstitutionsTypes);
            model.addAttribute("listOfInstitutionsNames", listOfInstitutionsNames);
            model.addAttribute("listOfDates", listOfDates);
            return "search";    
        }


        @RequestMapping(value ="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String SecondActionPage(@RequestParam String particularDate, 
                                       @RequestParam String nameOfInstitution, 
                                       @RequestParam String typeName,
                                       Model model) throws Exception {


                if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution.trim() !="" && typeName.trim()=="") {                   
                    controllerSupportClass.findWithDateAndName(nameOfInstitution, particularDate, model);                   
                } else if(particularDate.trim() !="" && nameOfInstitution.trim() =="" && typeName.trim() !="") {                    
                    controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDateAndType(typeName, particularDate, model);                   
                } else if(particularDate.trim() !="" && nameOfInstitution.trim() =="" && typeName.trim() ==""){         
                    controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDate(particularDate, model);    
                } else if(particularDate.trim() !="" && nameOfInstitution.trim() !="" && typeName.trim() !="") {
                    throw new Exception("Search by choose all parameters is not exceptable");   
                } else {    
                    throw new Exception("You didn't put any search parameters");    
                }           
            return "search";
        }

}
```

**It gives me an error like this:**

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found
>   for HTTP request with URI [/controller/] in DispatcherServlet with
>   name 'appServlet' Hibernate: select distinct creationda0_.DATE_ID as
>   DATE1_0_, creationda0_.CHILD_ADMISSION_DATE as CHILD2_0_,
>   creationda0_.CHILD_GO_SCHOOL_DATE as CHILD3_0_,
>   creationda0_.PARTICULAR_DATE as PARTICULAR4_0_, creationda0_.VERSION
>   as VERSION0_ from CREATION_DATE creationda0_ WARN :
>   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
>   S1009 ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Value
>   '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date Jun 19, 2013
>   3:26:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with
>   path [/controller] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   execute query] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: Value
>   '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date

If you need my Entity class it's here I'm using `Date` from `java.util`, but I go with `@Temporal` annotation to convert it from SQL to unit `Date` as I understand:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CREATION_DATE")
public class CreationDate implements Serializable {


    private int dateId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="DATE_ID")
        public int getDateId() {
            return dateId;
        }

        public void setDateId(int dateId) {
            this.dateId = dateId;
        }


    private int version;

        @Version
        @Column(name="VERSION")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }


    private Date particularDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
        @Column(name="PARTICULAR_DATE")
        public Date getParticularDate() {
            return particularDate;
        }

        public void setParticularDate(Date particularDate) {
            this.particularDate = particularDate;
        }


    private Date childGoSchoolDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
        @Column(name="CHILD_GO_SCHOOL_DATE")
        public Date getChildGoSchoolDate() {
            return childGoSchoolDate;
        }

        public void setChildGoSchoolDate(Date childGoSchoolDate) {
            this.childGoSchoolDate = childGoSchoolDate;
        }


    private Date childAdmissionDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
        @Column(name="CHILD_ADMISSION_DATE")
        public Date getChildAdmissionDate() {
            return childAdmissionDate;
        }

        public void setChildAdmissionDate(Date childAdmissionDate) {
            this.childAdmissionDate = childAdmissionDate;
        }


}
```

Assuming that the problem with data type conversion is because MVC uses `String`, but the actual type is `Date`.

Comment: Right thank you. but does it just show me it like ""yyyy-MM-dd" I'm not looking forward to have time also.

Comment: @chancea I hope you aren't suggesting that the Date class can't represent dates before 1970.

Comment: @d.v.a you can format it however you like, it is just a long value that represents the milliseconds.  If you need time also you should look into [java.sql.timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: @chancea milliseconds is a 64-bit long. There are enough bits to go back to 292000000 BCE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to process 0000-00-00 date in jdbc MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633747/how-to-process-0000-00-00-date-in-jdbc-mysql-query)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In MySql `'0000-00-00'` is considered a valid date, but it can't be repesented as java.sql.Date.

You could use a query that returns NULL in case date is `'0000-00-00'`, or the actual value otherwise:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN `date`!='0000-00-00' THEN `date` END new_date
FROM
  yourtable
```

or you can add to your datasource connection string this:

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

and dates as `'0000-00-00'` will be automatically converted to NULL.

Comment: Thank you. I will try, I'm using hibernate and how can I go with it correspond on your answer.?

Comment: @ fthiella Thank you for your help we was on right way, it's generate 0000-00-00 instead null I solve it with adding to my datasourse file this: zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8

Comment: This helped. For the ones trying to run an application importing a library that maps some tables in mysql inside Spring Boot, this was caused by the lack of naming convention: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl inside application.properties. Hibernate started, created new columns with empty values inside tables, and thus this exception. The convertToNull saved from exceptions but even valid dates inside mysql tables appeared null inside the application, because they were coming from the new (and empty) columns.

Answer (score 24):

Append the following statement with the JDBC-mysql protocol:

```
"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8"
```

for Example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/infra?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

Comment: Simple and Elegant!
`private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Your_DB_Name?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";`

Comment: Great advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Add `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`  to the jdbc connection URL.

```
String jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/master_schema?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
```

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT always the `NULL` issue. Your data set may contain dates in the format `05/23/2005` and running the loader will cause it to insert `0000-00-00` into your DATE type column. Invalid `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00') (from MySQL manual)

While retrieving using a `SELECT`, MySQL retrieves the value in `YYYY-MM-DD'` format in the range of `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`. So all your `0000-00-00` starts screwing up.

So watch out not just for `NULLs` but also for date formats not supported by MySQL.

There is RELAXED mode supported where any character can be used as delimiters like `/` in `05/23/2005` - you may want to try that as well.

Answer (score 3):

For me simply the following worked. Thanks to **@Yogesh H Bhosale** and **@fthiella** answer in this same Q-A thread I found the hint, and improved it.

Code Snippet:
***Connection String:***

```
private static String CONNECTION_STR = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/water_billing?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
```

***SQL-DB implementation:***

And to prevent from Null Pointer Exception at the time of data(date field) extraction from the returned data set I add the following code to the Prepared Statement.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STR,USERNAME,PASSWORD);   //   Get connection to the DB to execute the query. You will have to handle exceptions here too..
String SQL = "SELECT dateField FROM my_payments_tbl";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
LocalDate prvPaymentDate = null;

while (rs.next())
{
     // Following is the next Important line.
     prvPaymentDate = (rs.getDate(1) != null) ? rs.getDate(1).toLocalDate() : null;    // Checks if it comes as a Null or a Real java.sql.Date object.

     // Depending on the value of the column in the current row, prvPaymentDate could be null.
     // Specially as we instructed via the Connection String, 0000-00-00 00:00:00 will come now as SQL NULL objects.
     // So we filter out them in the above line and assigns null, instead of LocalDate objects.
     if (prvPaymentDate != null)
        System.out.println("date "+prvPaymentDate.toString());
}
```

**Note:**
Please read all the comments within the answer for good understanding.

Answer (score 2):

My wild guess is that you're using MySQL, your date columns are not mandatory and hence can contain NULLs, but MySQL does idiotic things and will return 0000-00-00 instead of NULL unless you fix the MySQL server settings.

Comment: Ahh I bet it is a NULL issue.

Comment: Right. Just is suppose to be some bugs between hibernate and msql.