# Why strtotime php function is not working properly?

Tags: php

Hello guys I am using strtotime to change the date format from Y-m-d to d-m-Y , It is working properly but where the date is not defined in database (0000-00-00) it is showing 30-11--0001 where date is not defined in the database

```
$datee=$row['datee'];
     $date1= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($datee));

echo $date1;
```

If the date is 2018-10-05 then it is showing 05-10-2018 but if date is not define in database like 0000-00-00 then it is showing 30-11--0001

Comment: The part which reads `--0001` is the year negative one preceded by the dash in front of `-Y`. Sounds like an edge-case bug.

Comment: What do you want the date to return if it is not defined in the database?

Comment: fwiw, when you're getting dates from the DB then you can specify the format you wish to be given to your PHP code so that you do not have to worry about these types of things.

Comment: check your data, https://ideone.com/dCiXay You probably need to fix your default value.

Comment: Ok i solved it by using if loop , thanks for your concern , I just wanted to know why does it returning this

Comment: @Alex r u sure? Your demo demonstrates the reproduction of `30-11--0001`. Can you explain why that result is to be expected?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've changed my comment. I agree that php has weird bug for that string '0000-00-00', but that string is not "not defined" variable. So we just need to reset default value for table to not store those zeros. If you can check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44bfae/1 and change default back to zero - that brings an exception even for java https://stackoverflow.com/a/17196386/4421474 . so it seem there is something that we expect, but smarter people do not :-)