# Prepared Statement for tons of columns

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a table with 74 columns, and I want to insert data into it. Is there a way to insert only 5 columns in that table and leave the rest as null? The columns aren't in order either, it might be

```
    ps.setInt(1, 1);
    ps.setInt(7, "Steve");
    ps.setInt(10, time);
```

etc....

Must I fill in data for every column?

The structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vbulletin_user` (
    `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `usergroupid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `membergroupids` char(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `displaygroupid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `password` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `passworddate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    `email` char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `styleid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `parentemail` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `homepage` char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `icq` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `aim` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `yahoo` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `msn` char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `skype` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `showvbcode` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `showbirthday` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
    `usertitle` char(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `customtitle` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `joindate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `daysprune` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastvisit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastactivity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastpost` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastpostid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `posts` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reputation` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
    `reputationlevelid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `timezoneoffset` char(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `pmpopup` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `avatarid` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `avatarrevision` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `profilepicrevision` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sigpicrevision` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `options` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '33570831',
    `birthday` char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `birthday_search` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    `maxposts` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    `startofweek` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `ipaddress` char(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `referrerid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `languageid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `emailstamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `threadedmode` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `autosubscribe` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    `pmtotal` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pmunread` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `salt` char(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `ipoints` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `infractions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `warnings` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `infractiongroupids` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `infractiongroupid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `adminoptions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `profilevisits` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `friendcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `friendreqcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vmunreadcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vmmoderatedcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `socgroupinvitecount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `socgroupreqcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pcunreadcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pcmoderatedcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gmmoderatedcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `assetposthash` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `fbuserid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `fbjoindate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fbname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `logintype` enum('vb','fb') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'vb',
    `fbaccesstoken` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `newrepcount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `bloggroupreqcount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `showblogcss` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
    KEY `usergroupid` (`usergroupid`),
    KEY `username` (`username`),
    KEY `birthday` (`birthday`,`showbirthday`),
    KEY `birthday_search` (`birthday_search`),
    KEY `referrerid` (`referrerid`),
    KEY `fbuserid` (`fbuserid`),
    KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Comment: Do you rather mean `74` columns? You should consider normalizing your tables first. 74 is too much.

Comment: Yes, there's 74 pieces of data for the table.

Comment: Are these fields `nullable` in the database design?

Comment: You can define the columns to fill in the `INSERT` statement: `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, then execute the query. Of course, this will work if the columns of your table support `NULL` value.

Comment: @RohitJain sometimes a normalization can't be done if the table is old enough e.g. a legacy bank application that exists since 1970's that holds the data of the customers, where `Date` fields never existed and used at least 3 `int` fields for year, month and day, and probably since the database engine didn't support referential integrity so it has like 5 fields for family data and probable this multiplied by 6: wife, father, mother and 3 children.

Comment: @RohitJain and the bank doesn't want to afford a refactoring on such system since *it's working and doesn't present any problems*

Comment: The structure of the table has been added to the main post. Would I still be able to do as luigi suggested?

Comment: @Tyluur no it won't work since almost all your fields have the `NOT NULL` constraint. *Must I fill in data for every column?* based in the current design of your table, **yes**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I tested it on mysql installed in my system and it worked. All fields that are `NOT NULL` got a `DEFAULT` value in schema which will be used in case when no value is provided. ` .

Comment: here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47bb4/1/0). I have changed the `default date` for `passworddate` and `birthday_search` columns for the same reason that I gave in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As  Luiggi Mendoza stated in the comment, the query will work.
example in this query:

```
ps=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO vbulletin_user(userid,username,password,email) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
ps.setInt(1,1);
ps.setString(2,"scott");
ps.setString(3,"tiger");
ps.setString(4,"email@example.com");
```

the default values will be inserted for other columns as they are mentioned in the schema.
And You should set the default value for `Date` to some specific date instead of `0000-00-00` like in your `passworddate` and `birthday_search` column since it would lead to [some exception when accessing by java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633747/how-to-process-0000-00-00-date-in-jdbc-mysql-query)

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47bb4/1/0), in this I just changed the value for `default date` for `passworddate` and `birthday_search` columns.

Comment: -1: In my comment I stated that *this will work if the columns of your table support `NULL` value*, but if you **read** the table DML, almost all the fields have `NOT NULL` in it. Next time test the code before posting it as answer (by the way, I tested this on a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6592/1)).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I tested it on mysql installed in my system and it worked. All fields that are `NOT NULL` got a `DEFAULT` value in schema which will be used in case when no value is provided. And in sqlfiddle, you didn't saw this error `DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.` .

Comment: Yes, sorry, I posted this comment almost at 3 a.m. here in my country. I retested it and find that worked (except for the date fields). Downvote removed.