# Getting a Date datatype in mysql

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to get a Date datatype from my database in SQL. 
But I get this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select movie_id, movie_name, movie_dateBorrowed from  movie_tbl where movie_borrower = '"+userUserID+"'");
                if(rs.next()){
                    String moviename = rs.getString("movie_name");
                    Date moviedateborrowed = rs.getDate("movie_dateBorrowed");
                    if(movieDB!="0000-00-00"){
                        Date moviedateborrowed = rs.getDate("movie_dateBorrowed");
                        dates.add(moviedateborrowed);        
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable.");
                    }
                }
```

Any help would make my day. Thanks

PS. I'm using Netbeans as my IDE.

Comment: what is the column type for column 'movie_dateBorrowed'? Make sure its date

Comment: I think this is a better match: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633747/how-to-process-0000-00-00-date-in-jdbc-mysql-query  It has different good answers.

Comment: @Arvind Yes it is a date.

Comment: check you rs.getDate("movie_dateBorrowed") for "0000-00-00". use inline code like a ternary operator : check (getdate=="0000-00-00")?"":getdate().
But 0000-00-00 is not a proper data as anybody can see and tell. take precautions while inserting such kind of data use NULL.

Comment: I had faced similar problem during my Graduation project. So after lots of search, I decided to store the Date as string and retrieve as string. If you are just storing in database and then Displaying it in database then this may solve your problem. If your problem is something else say you want to find bookings done in between two date's than you might face little problem but that also has a solution. All the best. Ready to help if more query's from your side.

Comment: I checked the date and it's not "0000-00-00". It is actually "2014-01-14" And I don't know where the program gets the "0000-00-00" as I have no data that has null or "0000-00-00"

Comment: @CronasDeSe : hello !! Have you seen my answer ? Not even one response, why ?

Answer (score 0):

for **Derby** the smallest value for the `Date` == `0002-11-30`

other Databases may have another limit.

Test it like

```
 if(rs.next()){
      String moviename = rs.getString("movie_name");
      movies.add(moviename);
      String DateStr = rs.getString("movie_dateBorrowed");
      if (DateStr != "0000-00-00") {
         Date moviedateborrowed = rs.getDate("movie_dateBorrowed");
         dates.add(moviedateborrowed);
      } else ...
 ...
 }
```

in the else statement you can use `dates.add` to add `0002-11-30` (Derby)

Comment: Oh. Sorry! I was busy doing other projects I forgot to check on stackoverflow again. Btw, I tried your solution, but still it gets the same error, I tried putting

    else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The date is not valid.");
    }

But this does not show up, so it means that it executes if. But still thanks for your answer. Sorry for the so late response.

Comment: @CronasDeSe : can you show us the value of : `DateStr`  : from code `String DateStr = rs.getString("movie_dateBorrowed");`

Comment: Wait, it still doesn't show. I tried to remove the rs.getDate("movie_dateBorrowed");. I just put String DateStr = rs.getString("movie_dateBorrowed"); System.out.println(DateStr); but it still shows the same error.

Comment: please `update` your question and add the new code with the part `System.out.println(DateStr);`

Comment: Updated. Thanks. Sorry for the really late replies because it's our hell week last week.